# How do I get the latest version of FreeFileSync (currently 9.7) to run in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, compiling

Download the latest version here (currently v9.7): https://www.freefilesync.org/download.php

[Building from source](https://www.freefilesync.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4941) is an absolute nightmare (I've spent ~20 hrs on that endeavor...) and just leads to [similar problems](https://www.freefilesync.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4941#p16737), so perhaps we can make the binary for Ubuntu 16.04 work instead?

Download the 16.04 binary, extract it, navigate to the folder, and do `./FreeFileSync`. I now get this error:

> ./FreeFileSync: error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So, I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613940/4561887) and did:

```
./configure
make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Now when I do `./FreeFileSync` I get the following errors:

```
./FreeFileSync: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./FreeFileSync)
./FreeFileSync: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by ./FreeFileSync)
./FreeFileSync: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./FreeFileSync)
./FreeFileSync: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./FreeFileSync)
./FreeFileSync: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./FreeFileSync)
```

**How do I get FreeFileSync v9.7 to run in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?**

If you can get it to work by compiling it that's fine, or by installing something else that's fine. I've already compiled GCC from scratch a half dozen times in my attempts, so I just need someone to help guide me here (not in compiling gcc, but in getting FreeFileSync 9.7 to run in Ubuntu 14.04 remember). Ultimately I just don't know how to accomplish this, despite the fact it seems to me like it shouldn't be such a complicated task.

Unfortunately, upgrading my distribution to Ubuntu 16.04LTS is not an option.

Comment: Might well be more trouble then its worth. Old distros have old libs, which likely are incompatible with the newest version. And if you manage to upgrade the libs, you'll have upgraded half the distro along the way. 14.04 will be eol in 15 months, like it or not, and planning an upgrade in advance is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

For next 14 months I recommend to create [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS inside and install FreeFileSync into it:

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/xenial.conf
[xenial]
description=Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
directory=/srv/chroot/xenial
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/xenial

sudo debootstrap xenial /srv/chroot/xenial

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /srv/chroot/xenial/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

schroot -c xenial -u root apt-get update
schroot -c xenial -u root apt-get install software-properties-common sudo
schroot -c xenial -u root apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libsm6 # for FreeFileSync
```

Then you can download FreeFileSync as usual

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://download936.mediafire.com/qayx2xg6bkyg/rhia0pqcfqjmu2w/FreeFileSync_9.7_Ubuntu_16.04_64-bit.tar.gz
# if wget does not work download it manually to ~/Downloads
tar -xvzf FreeFileSync_9.7_Ubuntu_16.04_64-bit.tar.gz
```

Then try to launch it from terminal

```
schroot -c xenial env DISPLAY=:0.0 ~/Downloads/FreeFileSync/FreeFileSync
```

If it works you may want to create desktop shortcut for it as follows:

```
cat <<EOF > ~/Desktop/FreeFileSync.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=FreeFileSync
Comment=Keep files and folders synchronized
Exec=schroot -c xenial env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/$USER/Downloads/FreeFileSync/FreeFileSync
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=freefilesync
MimeType=application/x-freefilesync-ffs;application/x-freefilesync-batch
Categories=Utility;FileTools;GTK;
StartupWMClass=FreeFileSync
StartupNotify=true
EOF

chmod +x ~/Desktop/FreeFileSync.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll give this a shot when I get a chance. I've never used schroot or chroot before and it's always a bit intimidating to figure out how to use and understand a new tool---but that's what I've been doing for decades so I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I added desktop shortcut creation part.

Comment: Those are quite the cat commands there. Understanding all of this is going to take me a while.